# API Discovering its own URL Golang

Tags: go

I've created an API in Go that can search or directly access an `Element` via ElasticSearch, which then adds some data to the JSON payload, and returns that to the user. When searching I'm returning a list of `Elements`, and I'd like to be able to give a direct URL to the specific `Element` should the user wish to get more information.

**However I can't ascertain how the application is supposed to figure out its own URL. In the event that it can't, what would be a reasonable alternative for the URL itself?**

Using net/http package and gorilla/mux for net based things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "reverse" a gorilla/mux url by looking up the route by name, and generating the url with [`Route.URL`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Route.URL)

You will want to name your route, so that you can easily look it up via [`Router.Get`](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#Router.Get).

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}", ArticleHandler).
  Name("article")
```

And once you have the route, you can build a url by passing the parameters to URL

```
url, err := r.Get("article").URL("category", "technology", "id", "42")
// "/articles/technology/42"
```

Note that if you want the host to be inserted automatically, it will need to be defined on your route:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Host("{subdomain}.domain.com").
  HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}", ArticleHandler).
  Name("article")

// url.String() will be "http://news.domain.com/articles/technology/42"
url, err := r.Get("article").URL("subdomain", "news",
                                 "category", "technology",
                                 "id", "42")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good info. Though it looks like I'm not able to get the host without defining what the host is, which I find to be a little sloppy for what I'm trying to do.